# Are there any libraries to allow Python or Ruby to get info from SVN?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, svn

I'm looking for plugins that will allow my codebase to interact with, browse, and poll an SVN server for information about a repository.

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) can do this, but I was hoping there was an easy-to-use library available to accomplish the task, rather than trolling through the Trac codebase.  Googling for this returns mostly vague results about storing your code **in** and SVN repository, which is far from what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Subversion ships with Ruby bindings. There is some information on Ruby SVN bindings [here](http://www.oneofthewolves.com/2007/03/06/ruby-subversion-bindings-finally-some-documentation/) and [here](http://alistairisrael.wordpress.com/2007/09/19/using-the-subversion-ruby-bindings/).